# Can AQuery load image from a HTML page?

Tags: android, android-query

I just tested AQuery's image loading based on [this tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading). It works well, when I use on an URL like *example.com/xy.jpg*. But what if I want to load an image that is displayed by a page (for example a php page)?

If my url is like this: *example.com/showimage.php*, I get a message of this: *SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null*.

Does AQuery support deferred image loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can **if the PHP page redirects to a valid image.**